# C# Windows Service can not use GetSection() with custom ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, windows-services, app-config

I am getting exceptions when trying to use custom app.config sections in my Windows Service.  I have written custom sections in other apps successfully, so pretty sure I have the mechanics right and there is just something going on when Windows Services are involved.  I can include the app.config Xml if needed.

**First Attempt**

I have the following code in a C# windows service constructor:

```
int systemErrorWindowSeconds = 
    ServiceSettings.Current.ExceptionHandling.SystemErrorWindowSeconds;
```

And ServiceSettings (the important bits) is as follows:

```
public class ServiceSettings : ConfigurationSection
{
    private static ServiceSettings settings;

    static ServiceSettings()
    {
        var config = 
            ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( ConfigurationUserLevel.None );

        settings = config.GetSection( "serviceSettings" ) as ServiceSettings;
    }

    public static ServiceSettings Current { get { return settings;  } }
```

When I attempt to access `ServiceSettings.Current` I get the following exception:

```
Application: BTR.Evolution.Service.exe  
Framework Version: v4.0.30319  
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info:    System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(System.String[], System.Configuration.SectionInput, Boolean, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
    at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection(System.String)
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.ServiceSettings..cctor() Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.ServiceSettings.get_Current()
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.EvolutionService..ctor(System.String[])
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

**Second Attempt:**

I changed my ServiceSettings class to use GetSection like:

```
static ServiceSettings()
{
    settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection( "serviceSettings" ) as ServiceSettings;
}
```

I get the following exception (mostly same as above but uses ConfigurationManager and few more GetSectionRecursive calls)

```
Application: BTR.Evolution.Service.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: 
  System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(System.String[], System.Configuration.SectionInput, Boolean, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String)
    at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)
    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.ServiceSettings..cctor() Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.ServiceSettings.get_Current()
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.EvolutionService..ctor(System.String[])
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

**Third Attempt**

I changed my ServiceSettings constructor to try:

```
var customConfig = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile );

settings = customConfig.GetSection( "serviceSettings" ) as ServiceSettings;
```

And I got the following exception.  Basically, the settings variable was assigned to null (no 'configuration manager' exceptions) so the caller using the object gets a null exception.

```
Application: BTR.Evolution.Service.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319 
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. 
Exception Info: System.NullReferenceException 
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.EvolutionService..ctor(System.String[]) 
    at BTR.Evolution.Service.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

**Final Attempt**

I changed my ServiceSettings constructor to try to use an assembly resovler.

```
Func<object, ResolveEventArgs, System.Reflection.Assembly> getAssembly = 
    ( sender, args ) => typeof( ServiceSettings ).Assembly;

var resolveHandler = new System.ResolveEventHandler( getAssembly );

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += resolveHandler;

var customConfig = 
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile );

settings = customConfig.GetSection( "serviceSettings" ) as ServiceSettings;

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= resolveHandler;
```

But I got the exact same result as my third attempt.

Any advice on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Comment: Process Monitor is likely to be a useful diagnostic tool, to see whether .NET is opening the correct configuration file and if not just what it is doing wrong.  You can download it from the Microsoft web site.

Comment: Catastrophe happened...my PC crashed...sorry for delay.  Finally got back to this.  Process Monitor is showing it is hitting the right file, yet it is not correctly reading the settings applied.  It has CREATE, READ, READ, CLOSE for the file C:\BTR\Source\Evolution.Service\BTR.Evolution.Service\bin\Debug\BTR.Evolution.Service.exe.config but any setting changes I put in there are not read.  Is this what you were wanting me to confirm?

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking, exactly, but it's good to know that it is definitely reading the file you expected it to.  Have you tried running the same constructor with the same configuration file but as a normal program rather than a service?  It might be something as simple as a syntax error in the configuration file.

Comment: Hmm, bit embarrassed.  I made a new console app as suggested using same code and settings and it worked.  So re-examined my Windows Service and I was trying to use a custom assembly resolver to locate the config file/section.  I'm assuming that when I wrote service originally, I was having problems and I tried this custom resolver (which still didn't work).  That is when I posted this question.  But for the heck of it, I put back just the standard `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` (second method from above) mechanics to get the custom section and it worked.  Can't explain it.

Comment: No worries.  I recommend you close the question.

Comment: Can I close or only vote to close?  Appears the later.

Comment: If I remember correctly, a vote to close from the owner closes a question immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, bit embarrassed. I made a new console app as suggested using same code and settings and it worked. So re-examined my Windows Service and I was trying to use a custom assembly resolver to locate the config file/section. I'm assuming that when I wrote service originally, I was having problems and I tried this custom resolver (which still didn't work). That is when I posted this question. But for the heck of it, I put back just the standard ConfigurationManager.GetSection (second method from above) mechanics to get the custom section and it worked. Can't explain it